# Can we configure two RetryConfiguration classes in Spring Retry?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-retry

Can we configure the two retryConfigurations classes in Spring Batch for use in Tasklet? I have complex stuff so need two different retry mechanism. Just wanted to understand which retry template should be called out ?

Anyone please give me quick pointers ?

```
@EnableRetry
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ABCRetryConfigurations {
    @Value("${retryPeriod}")
    private int retryIntervalInSeconds;

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryIntervalInSeconds * 1000);

        RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        return template;
    }
}
```

and

```
@EnableRetry
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class XYZRetryConfigurations {
    @Value("${retryPeriod}")
    private int retryIntervalInSeconds;

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate XXXXXRetryTemplate() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryIntervalInSeconds * 1000);

        RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        return template;
    }
}
```

Here is my code?

```
public class XXXXXXXX {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XXXXXXXXX.class);

    @Autowired
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate; 

    private Set<String> abcFileNames;
    private ChunkContext paramChunkContext; 

    public XXXXXXXX(Set<String> abcFileNames, SendXXXTasklet tasklet, ChunkContext paramChunkContext) {
        this.abcFileNames = abcFileNames;
        this.tasklet = tasklet;
        this.paramChunkContext = paramChunkContext;
    }

    public RepeatStatus executeXXXXRetry() {
        // Retry configuration
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy( fixedBackOffPolicy );

        return retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
            return tasklet.XXX(abcFileNames, paramChunkContext);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just wanted to understand which retry template should be called out ?

Which one should be called out is a decision that is up to you by telling the Spring container which retry template to autowire. In your example, you have two `RetryTemplate` beans (`retryTemplate` and `billingRetryTemplate`) and you want to autowire a `RetryTemplate retryTemplate` in the `XXXXXXXX` class. In your case, it is the `retryTemplate` bean that will be autowired by name (by default the method name is the bean name). You can use `@Primary` or `@Qualifier` to be more explicit about which one to use.

You can find more details about this in the Spring Framework docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java